# Using Android device manager to get the SIM details of located device

Tags: android-device-manager

Thanks to [this question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/895598/how-to-track-a-android-tablet-in-the-same-network-using-mac-address), I was able to locate my mobile which was stolen a month back, but after using ADM (Android Device Manager) service, it notifies the tracked device that "Your location has been shared", but now I am getting this message "Your device's location access is turned off".

I suspect that the thief turned off this feature after I successfully located the device with accuracy of 20 meters, in fact during the last instances I could clearly see the stolen device moving along a definite trajectory as I suspect the thief would have panicked on seeing the ADM tracked messages notifications on the stolen phone. The tracked location is also very close location and very familiar to me which means I can probably get back my device.

Since the tracked device shares the location info, does it also share the other details like which SIM card mobile number the thief has installed? Can we get this info from Google?

Comment: I don't know.. you can ask Google if that information are available or not. You can just lock (and reset device password) and ring it remotely and generally cause inconvenience to the thief (and hopefully you can locate the thief by finding someone who didn't manage to unlock or turn off their own phone). Good luck.

Comment: but it shows lock and erase?

Comment: When you hover your mouse over "Lock" it actually say "Lock and reset device password" so if you can lock out the thief out of their "stolen" phone...

Comment: AFAIK, no, Android Device Manager (and Google) can't share other details like SIM card mobile number.